# How to set graph (and not figure !) size in matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, size

I am trying to get a graph in which the square dots touch each other without overlapping. For that, I need a defined graph size so I can adapt my squares' size.

**The problem is that I found a lot of ways to control the figure( graph + axes, labels and title) size, but not the graph size itself.**

Just so you know, my graph represents dots in some defined position that colors depends on the corresponding value in the matrix (I wish I could send an example, but I do not have enough reputation it seems...)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the axes size within the figure using [add_axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.5,0.5])
plt.show()
```

Where the argument to add_axes is rect = l,b,w,h and the units are the fraction of the figure size.

However, if you're trying to get squares that touch but don't overlap, you may want to use [imshow](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

```
z = [[5,2,7],[8,1,5],[3,4,10]]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(z,extent=[3,6,6,9],interpolation='none')

plt.show()
```

[image: squares plotted with imsho]